# Entity framework linq to entities

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Previously when I wanted obtain related data in an sql query I would join tables, however now in linq to entities I want to get data from a table that is related to the table through another table. I don't know how to perform this sort of query in linq to entities. If someone could help that would be good.

The example is a table named person which has a relationship to table users which is related to table roles. I want to be able to obtain a person that has a particular role. Since person is only related to user and indirectly through user to role, I'm not sure of the query. Also using navigation properties doesn't get me all the way there either.

Any information would be good. Here is an example of the database structure:

[db structure http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/4540/persons.jpg](http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/4540/persons.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

If you using the generator in VS (ie, drap drop the data table and diagram and keys are all set in db), then the thing you are asking could be already there automatically.

e.g.

```
from Person in Context.Persons
where Person.Name == "PETER PAN"
select Person.User.Role.RoleName;
```

Exact name need to refer to the code generator, but this is the idea. Linq to entities will help to map foreign keys and those for you.

Edit

Actually I haven't tried using include. But according to [msdn:include method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx), the include should show the object hierarchy to work. So, for your query to work, try:

```
from c in db.Persons.Include("aspnet_Users").Include("aspnet_Roles")
    where c.aspnet_Users.aspnet_Roles.RoleName == "Role" select c
```

And moreover, will you consider start from roles?

```
from r in db.aspnet_Roles
where r.RoleName == "ROLE"
select r.aspnet_Users.Persons
```

Comment: what i was orginally looking for was all users in a particular role not the role for each person. The problem with doing that was that aspnet_Users.aspnet_Roles.RoleName was not available for some reason...

Comment: You mean mapping all users that belongs to a particular group, right? Could you post more here to see why it's not working?

Comment: return (from c in db.Persons.Include("aspnet_Users") where c.aspnet_Users.aspnet_Roles.RoleName == "Role" select c); is what i was querying with, RoleName however doesn't seem to exist... ("Role" is just a placeholder, i use an actual role when querying)

Comment: i thought about starting from roles and figured that would work, but i wanted to return a person. I though the syntax for include was to space the related tables using a dot syntax but will try with multiple include methods.

Comment: No, no good doing it like that either, you would have to think there is a solution for something that is so simple when using sql joins.

Comment: Can't use the roles option you provided either can't navigate from aspnet_Users to Persons...

Comment: Just a thought, have you test whether the entity is correct? like can you simply do (from u in db.aspnet_Users where UserName = "dfklds" select u.Persons) ?

Comment: (from u in db.aspnet_Users where u.UserName == "dfklds" select u.Persons) that works yes

Answer (score 1):

```
(from u in db.aspnet_Users.Include("Person") 
 from c in db.aspnet_Roles 
 where c.RoleName == "role" 
 select u.Persons);
```

Worked it out thanks for trying though.

Comment: it still feels a little unnatural to write something like that after writing sql for so long...

Comment: return (from u in db.Persons from c in db.aspnet_Roles where c.RoleName == "" select u); even better version

Comment: I've using Linq 2 Sql for some time and to me it is quite natural (except that when you need to think about performance). The only major different is that try not to think in sql's way when using Linq, and your question is quite unusual and I am sure in Linq 2 Sql I never encounter such situation (and I even never used Include before)